# Videos within a Twitter Bootstrap carousel, doesn't stop playing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using the latest version of Twitter Bootstrap, and embedding Vimeo videos through an iframe... I built a simple carousel with the help of BootSnipp (Extend Carousel) and rather than placing image thumbnails, I've added videos. However, I've run into a problem where... when you play the first video and click on another video, the first keeps playing. I need the to stop the videos when another video is clicked.

Many other post deal with YouTube and the ones I've seen with Vimeo don't seem to help.

Comment: Please post your code. Even better, create an example using JSFiddle so that others can play with it and help you, possibly, more quickly.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used BootSnipp, but the following works with vanilla Bootstrap.

You need to use the [Vimeo JavaScript API](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) to manually pause the video when the Bootstrap carousel slides to the next slide. This is simplest using Vimeo's [Froogaloop library](https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript).

Give each Vimeo player `<iframe>` a unique id, pass that id as the "player_id", add a listener to Bootstrap's [`"slide.bs.carousel"` event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage) (in Bootstrap v3.0; I believe this was just `"slide"` in v2.3.2), and call Froogaloop.api("pause") on the corresponding Vimeo player.

When creating your Vimeo slides in the carousel, each Vimeo player should follow this basic setup (for clarity, I'm not including any options / attributes other than `id` and `src`; note `api=1` is a required query variable in your `src` attribute to activate the Vimeo JavaScript API):

```
<iframe id="player-id-N" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/yourVideoIDHere?player_id=player-id-N&api=1"></iframe>
```

(where N is some unique id, possibly your iterator index.)

(**EDIT:** *The `<iframe> id` and `player_id` are not necessary with this technique, but could still be useful depending on your setup.*)

Once your carousel is created, bind a handler to the slide event:

```
$myCarousel.on("slide.bs.carousel", function (event) {
    // Bootstrap carousel marks the current slide (the one we're exiting) with an 'active' class
    var $currentSlide = $myCarousel.find(".active iframe");

    // exit if there's no iframe, i.e. if this is just an image and not a video player
    if (!$currentSlide.length) { return; }

    // pass that iframe into Froogaloop, and call api("pause") on it.
    var player = Froogaloop($currentSlide[0]);
    player.api("pause");

});
```

[Here's a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ericsoco/wxMrf/) that doesn't use the `<iframe> id` or `player_id`, as mentioned in the **EDIT** above.

Comment: You rock dude! Thanks for this, just what I needed.